# Gradle command - can I use a file as command line arguments?

Tags: gradle, command-line

I would like to run a gradle task using a text file as command line arguments.

how can I do that in Windows and in Linux?

text file "run.txt" contains these arguments:

```
--tests com.tests.TestSpec.groovy -Denv=test
```

Tried running it in Windows machine as following and it did not work.

```
c:\MyProject\Tests>gradle < run.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can read a file content into a variable and use it as an argument as follows:

```
gradle "$(< run.txt)"
```

For Windows you can use something like this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %x in (run.txt) do gradle %x
```

This is the [Loop command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) example, which iterates over the run.txt file content, splitting it into the tokens and executing a `gradle` command over this tokens. `tokens=*` in this case means - process all tokens aon every line, by default it processes only the first token.

Buy IMHO, it's much easier to use a  batch files or shell script for such a tasks. For example in Linux you can simply create a file named `run.sh` with the content:

```
gradle --tests com.tests.TestSpec.groovy -Denv=test
```

make this file executable

```
chmod +x ./run.sh
```

and just run it as follows

```
./run.sh
```

In Windows it's even easier, since you don't need to make a batch file executable.